# Swf is not showing on chrome when it loads images from external XML source

Tags: html, google-chrome, flash

I have a swf file that's not working on chrome but works fine on other web browsers
you can test the flash from this url:

http://www.flawless-creativity.com/lifewindow/public/test-flash

In the as3 code I have a urlloader object that loads this xml file and handles it to show this slider:

http://www.flawless-creativity.com/lifewindow/public/services-xml

So I know the problem isn't in the as3 and not in the html embed code (I tried every embed code on the internet!), my only guess is that chrome doesn't allow swf files to load urls maybe for security... If that's true then how to solve this? Does the domain have to be trusted by google? And how to make google trust it?

Comment: It worked on my Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem ... In the as3 I added an enter_frame event listener , and in the event handler I started loading the xml URL